# Node zlib module not compressing a buffered string or Stream.Readable

Tags: node.js, zlib

I am using node's sitemap module which generates a string with the sitemap xml for my website. Since this is a very large sitemap, I would like to send it compressed (for example as sitemap.xml.gz). However, zlib module is not compressing it. It works if I stream it to a file in the server and then use this file to compress it, but I would like to be able to compress the generated xml string directly.
Here is what I am doing:

```
res.header('Content-Type', 'application/x-gzip');
res.header('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');        
res.header('ContentDisposition',
'attachment;filename="sitemap.xml.gzip"'); 

//testString is used here as an example, the generated sitemap xml will go here
var testString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
var input = Buffer.from(testString, 'utf8');
zlib.gzip(input, function(buferror, data) {
      res.send(data);
});
```

I've also tried instead of buffering the string, using the stream module and piping it through, like this:

```
var s = new stream.Readable();
s._read = function noop() {};
s.push(testString);
s.push(null);
s.pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(res);
```

However, I still get the same result, a sitemap.xml.gzip file that is **not** compressed. As I mentioned, I am able to get it to work if I put the xml string generated into a file in the server, and pipe it through like this:

```
var raw = fs.createReadStream('input.txt.gz');
raw.pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(res);
```

But I would like to avoid doing this workaround. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Content-Encoding: gzip`, you're allowing the browser to automatically decode (/gunzip) the contents of the response.

If you don't want that, don't set that header (also, your `ContentDisposition` header misses a hyphen, it should be `Content-Disposition`).